# How do I subdivide a Java curve into an odd number of segments?

Tags: java, java-2d, curves

I'm using QuadCurve2D.Double at this moment - although Im more than happy to use any other Curve type that can do this.

Basically, I am looking to cut a curve into three segments of equal length.

While QuadCurve2D contains some handy methods for dividing curves they all seem to be splitting them into two segments. I was thinking about splitting them further and pasting them back together - but this still doesn't help as even in this way I can only split into powers of two.

This is turning into a bit of a headache, to be honest, and I'm really hoping someone can help.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with dividing into six - except that it won't work: If I divide the original curve into two segments, and then divide again I end up with four. Then eight, sixteen, thirty-two etc. I basically never get a multiple of three. It's a mathematical impossibility.